# vuejs - using ivew tab with badge count

Tags: vue.js, iview

I'm refering to the docs http://v3.iviewui.com/components/tabs-en for allocating badge count for the tabs.

My HTML:

```
 <Tabs>
 <TabPane :label="label">
    Some Components here
 </TabPane>
 <Tabs>
```

And my JS:

```
<script>
import { Tabs, TabPane, Badge } from "iview";

export default {

  components: {
    Tabs,
    TabPane,
    Badge
  },
  data() {
    return {

      label: (h) => {
        return h("div", [
          h("span", "Result"),
          h("Badge", {
            props: {
              count: 5
            }
          })
        ]);
      }
    };
  }
```

But I keep receiving errors

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: Badge - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

I'm following exactly the same code from the sample but I'm not sure why the error is happening.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `"Badge"`, ie `h(Badge, { props...`

Comment: @Phil u r my life savior!I've been spending half day for this!!! thanks so much!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Here's the relevant documentation on the `createElement` (aka `h`) function ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments

Comment: @Phil Hi I have an extra question, am I possible to modify the badge `count` value from a method within the component ?

Comment: I'm really not sure at this stage. You're basically after reactive props but I'm not sure how to achieve this with render functions

Comment: @Phil alright!thanks mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, the problem is that you have quoted `"Badge"` in your render function which means Vue will be looking for a globally registered component of that name. What you want is to use the locally registered component

```js
h(Badge, {
  props: {
    count: 5
  }
})
```

---

As for your question from the comments...

> am I possible to modify the badge count value from a method within the component ?

Yes, I think so. All you should need to do is register a data property that you can modify via methods or whatever. For example

```js
data () {
  return {
    count: 5, // initial value,
    label: h => h('div', [
      h('span', 'Result'),
      h(Badge, {
        props: {
          count: this.count
        }
      })
    ])
  }
},
methods: {
  incrementCount () {
    this.count++
  }
}
```

<sub>Note: I tested this using some **very** simple components so I'm not 100% sure it will work with the iview ones.</sub>